# indexing many with nest and elasticsearch - unable to perform post on any of the nodes

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

i'm trying to index many documents using Nest to Elasticsearch. things run fine with there's a limited number of documents, but when i ramp up the number - from say 1000 to 50,000 it throws an error. i'm not convinced it's due to the number of documents - it could be bad data.

i'm trying to safeguard against bad data though - i'm only indexing documents that have an id. the id is being generated from one of my fields (upc). so i'm positive there's an id for every document. i'm also making sure my class object that it's serializing to/from has all nullable properties.

still, there's nothing informational that i can see that helps me in this error.

the error i get is..

```
Unable to perform request: 'POST' on any of the nodes after retrying 0 times
```

and here's the stacktrace when it throws the error:

```
 at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.Transport.RetryRequest[T](TransportRequestState`1 requestState, Uri baseUri, Int32 retried, Exception e) in c:\Projects\NEST\src\Elasticsearch.Net\Connection\Transport.cs:line 241
 at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.Transport.DoRequest[T](TransportRequestState`1 requestState, Int32 retried) in c:\Projects\NEST\src\Elasticsearch.Net\Connection\Transport.cs:line 215
 at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.Transport.DoRequest[T](String method, String path, Object data, IRequestParameters requestParameters) in c:\Projects\NEST\src\Elasticsearch.Net\Connection\Transport.cs:line 163
 at Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClient.DoRequest[T](String method, String path, Object data, BaseRequestParameters requestParameters) in c:\Projects\NEST\src\Elasticsearch.Net\ElasticsearchClient.cs:line 75
 at Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClient.Bulk[T](Object body, Func`2 requestParameters) in c:\Projects\NEST\src\Elasticsearch.Net\ElasticsearchClient.Generated.cs:line 45
 at Nest.RawDispatch.BulkDispatch[T](ElasticsearchPathInfo`1 pathInfo, Object body) in c:\Projects\NEST\src\Nest\RawDispatch.generated.cs:line 34
 at Nest.ElasticClient.<Bulk>b__d6(ElasticsearchPathInfo`1 p, BulkDescriptor d) in c:\Projects\NEST\src\Nest\ElasticClient-Bulk.cs:line 20
 at Nest.ElasticClient.Dispatch[D,Q,R](D descriptor, Func`3 dispatch, Boolean allow404) in c:\Projects\NEST\src\Nest\ElasticClient.cs:line 86
 at Nest.ElasticClient.Dispatch[D,Q,R](Func`2 selector, Func`3 dispatch, Boolean allow404) in c:\Projects\NEST\src\Nest\ElasticClient.cs:line 72
 at Nest.ElasticClient.Bulk(Func`2 bulkSelector) in c:\Projects\NEST\src\Nest\ElasticClient-Bulk.cs:line 15
 at Nest.ElasticClient.IndexMany[T](IEnumerable`1 objects, String index, String type) in c:\Projects\NEST\src\Nest\ElasticClient-Index.cs:line 44
 at ElasticsearchLoad.Program.BuildBulkApi() in c:\Projects\ElasticsearchLoad\ElasticsearchLoad\Program.cs:line 258
```

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you attempting to insert all 50,000 items in one bulk operation?

Comment: yes. i realized that's probably the issue just a few minutes ago. it seems it handle 10k at a time safely, but not 50k. is there a setting i can change to increase this capacity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to be limited in the effective bulk size you can send to Elasticsearch by a combination of your documents and Elasticsearch configuration. There is not any "single best answer" for this, but with some testing and configuration changes you should be able to achieve a suitable bulk indexing performance threshold. Here are some resources to assist you...

- [elasticsearch bulk indexing gets slower over time with constant number of indexes and documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757398/elasticsearch-bulk-indexing-gets-slower-over-time-with-constant-number-of-indexe)
- [Write heavy elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987667/write-heavy-elasticsearch)
- [Scaling Elasticsearch Part 1: Overview](http://gibrown.wordpress.com/2014/01/09/scaling-elasticsearch-part-1-overview/)

And for overall Sizing of Elasticsearch I would highly recommend reading - [Sizing Elasticsearch - Scaling up and out](https://www.found.no/foundation/sizing-elasticsearch/)

Comment: i'm now having problems indexing 10k documents by bulk indexing at only 1000 at a time! nothing has changed in my environment (it's a three node cluster) and i'm indexing directly to the primary - from the same machine! any more ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in multi-node cluster make sure your setup is the same for all nodes.

I am not sure if this can help you, but I had similar issue in 2 node cluster. I've was adding synonyms and setup the file for only master machine. I completely forgot to copy it over to 2nd node. This was causing the error above for me when creating new index that depended on that synonym file.

After I added synonym file and restarted 2nd node, everything went back to normal.